# Error: Output file ./.noxim_explorer.tmp corrupted, noxim tool

Tags: systemc

I am using SystemC and Network-on-chip simulator called "Noxim", which i've heard is very smooth and simple.

running make does not have problem

However, I am getting error when i run ./noxim_explorer sim.cfg

```
 deepthi@ubuntu:~/Downloads/noxim-code/other$ make
 make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

deepthi@ubuntu:~/Downloads/noxim-code/other$ ./noxim_explorer sim.cfg
# Exploring configuration space sim.cfg
Warning: Cannot extract parameter 'default'
Warning: Cannot extract parameter 'aggregation'
Warning: Cannot extract parameter 'explorer'
# simulation 1 of 120
```

./noxim   -routing xyz -sel random -dimx 8 -dimy 8  >./.noxim_explorer.tmp 2>&1
   Error: Output file ./.noxim_explorer.tmp corrupted

I think it comes from a cpp code, which I DO NOT own and, sincerely, dont fully understand. The code can be found bellow, and the full Noxim distribution can be found here:

The code is at [Noxim](https://github.com/alexayin/Noxim)/other/

Noxim_explorer.cpp and sim.cfg are strongly related to the lab im trying to do.

Please, if someone has solved this problem or have any idea, it would be very helpful.

FOR THE RECORD: I got stucked when trying to follow [this lab](http://access.ee.ntu.edu.tw/noxim/Lab2.pdf), 'cause I couldn't get any info in the matlab file

Comment: actual error -->                                 deepthi@ubuntu:~/Downloads/noxim-code/other$ ./noxim_explorer sim.cfg 
# Exploring configuration space sim.cfg                                                 
Warning: Cannot extract parameter 'default'                                            
Warning: Cannot extract parameter 'aggregation'                          
Warning: Cannot extract parameter 'explorer'                    
# simulation 1 of 120        ./noxim   -routing xyz -sel random -dimx 8 -dimy 8  >./.noxim_explorer.tmp 2>&1    
Error: Output file ./.noxim_explorer.tmp corrupted

Comment: post this error in your question

Answer (score 0):

You have not included -sim option which is the simulation time for running Noxim. See the below command for reference:

```
$ ./noxim_explorer sim.cfg 
# Exploring configuration space sim.cfg
# simulation 1 of 1
../bin/noxim -pir 0.024 poisson  -sim 500000 -warmup 10000 -size 8 8 -buffer 4 -traffic random -vertical mesh -throt normal -clean 1000  -routing zxy -sel thermal -dimx 8 -dimy 8 -dimz 4  >./.noxim_explorer.tmp 2>&1
```